# Modifying the icon in the firefox search box for a website's search engine/feature? (ie. GoogBinHoo, Wikipedia, Ebay, Superuser, etc)

Tags: firefox, search, icons

Does anybody know how to change the icon in the firefox search box to a custom made icon? For example if I wanted to change the google icon that is next to the google search box(or wikipedia, ebay, yahoo, bing, youtube, superuser :], etc), how would I do this? Is there a place where the file for this icon is stored that I can just modify? Could I change where firefox looks for this icon using about:config, userchrome.css, or some other way?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it out, but here is a link where you can create your own search plugin with your own custom image:  http://www.scriptsocket.com/firefoxplugins.php

Answer (score 1):

See this article : [Update Firefox’s search bar with new Google favicon](http://mozillalinks.org/wp/2008/05/update-the-google-search-plugin-icon-in-firefo/).

The data in the article and (especially) in the comments will tell you how to change this favicon to any 16x16 image, and also contains links to several such images:

1. Locate the `searchplugins` folder in your Firefox install folder.
   (typically `C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\` on Windows).
2. Open the `google.xml` file with a text editor.
3. Locate a section that starts with `<Image width="16" height="16">`. You will see it is followed by a long series of characters (such as "the encoded Google icon").
4. Replace it with this equally unreadable code:
   `<a href="http://www.mozillalinks.org//download/new_google_icon.txt">the new encoded Google icon</a>`
   Ensure the closing `</Image>` stays there and the text in-between is preserved.
5. Save the file and restart Firefox.

Comment: Never post link only answers as the links eventually all die.

Comment: @TomášZato: You are right in one sense: I just now tried accessing the above link and found that the Mozilla database was down. I resurrected the text from the Google Cache and pasted it above.